# svn command to see a tally of my changes

Tags: text-processing, subversion

Is there an SVN command that I can run to see a tally of all of my contributions?  Something like:

```
added 1800
deleted 15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about a single SVN command, but this seems to work:

```
svn log ${SVNURL} | awk '$1~/^r/ && $3=="username"{print $1}' | tr -d r |
while read rev; do svn diff -c $rev ${SVNURL}; done |
awk '/^\+\+\+/ || /^---/ {} /^\+/ {a++} /^-/ {d++} END {print a, "additions"; print d, "deletions"}'
```

Use your username instead of "username".

Comment: Any sufficiently complicated diff stats gathering script contains an ad-hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of diffstat?